# Magento 2 save configurable product issue

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.1 admin:-

When updating configurable product I am getting the following issue.

You don't have permission to access  /admin/catalog/product/validate/id/3316/type/configurable/store/0/set/4/key/11c0d458dc11fc072a5fdef7f5fb3fe633c433bbf0342175b987f10588ee2b2c/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that.

Just checked the server log and found that it was **mod_security** extension is enable.

That should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, How many products are you going to create or assign while creating configurable product.

I have experienced the same issue and I have sorted out with creating a configurable product with few product assignment.

I hope this may help you

Thanks

Comment: I am facing that issue with not only saving the products, I am facing that with saving configuration settings and etc.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the following error -:

=======

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /admin/catalog/product/validate/id/966/type/simple/store/0/set/9/

=====

Emailed hosting provider and they did change the setting at the server level. As soon as they changed the setting the error went straight away.

If they can’t change the setting on the server for some reason then look for product data. You will find malicious code, in our case it was iFrame code snippet which was causing that trouble.